# How Was Tarski's Undefinability Theorem Used?

Tags: logic

How is Tarski's undefinability used in the following stack-exchange answer(s)? To recall, the result is that for language $L$ for which [diagonal lemma](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/sup2.html) (i.e. $ZFC, PA)$ applies there is no formula $T$ with one free variable such that for all wffs $\phi$
$$L\vdash \phi\leftrightarrow T(\#(\phi))$$

Recall also that (please correct if wrong - I was not able to find a precise definition) a set $A$ is definable in $L$ if there is a function $\underline\space :S\rightarrow E$, where $S$ is some set and $E$ are the constants (or in some sense the objects) of language such that
$$A=\{x\in S:L\vdash\phi(\underline x)\}$$
Then a number (real or natural) is definable if the set $A$ contains only that number, and $S$ is then the set of natural or real numbers. The formula $\phi$ is said to define the number. (Note we work here in $ZFC$ and $L\vdash \phi$ can be taken to be the short hand for $Provable_L(\#(\phi))$)

How was Tarski used in

1. In $PA$ the "smallest number not definable in $PA$ in under $90$ characters" is  [not definable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662957/is-the-definition-of-the-following-set-controversial-x-mid-x-in-mathbb-n-s) in $PA$. (This actually seems to not need Tarski, rather the different language levels solve it).
2. [By Tarski](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44102/is-the-analysis-as-taught-in-universities-in-fact-the-analysis-of-definable-numb), we can not in general map $\phi$ to a real number it defines. In other words, we can not say that $\phi$ is true only at some point $r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple issues here.

---

To begin with, you're conflating **languages** (just sets of symbols) with **theories** (sets of sentences using the symbols in the language, in addition to the "purely logical" symbols - the latter being equality, parentheses, Booleans and quantifiers, and variables). For example, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is a theory in the language $\{\in\}$.

You're also mixing up definability (which is relative to a *structure*) with provable behavior (which is relative to a *theory*). Recall that a set $X\subseteq\mathfrak{A}^n$ is definable in $\mathfrak{A}$ iff there is some formula $\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)$ in the language of $\mathfrak{A}$ such that $$X=\{(a_1,...,a_n):\mathfrak{A}\models\varphi(a_1,...,a_n)\}.$$ *(See [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1154042/28111) for more about this.)*

Definability, not provability, is the notion which is important here: **provability is irrelevant to Tarski's undefinability theorem**.

*(OK, that's not strictly true, but it's true at the beginning.)*

In general definability is much "broader" than provable behavior in any sense. For example, Godel's incompleteness theorem says (for example) that there is some sentence $\sigma$ such that $\mathsf{PA}$ can't prove or disprove "$\sigma$ is a theorem of $\mathsf{PA}$," but the set of $\mathsf{PA}$-theorems **is** definable over the standard model $\mathfrak{N}=(\mathbb{N};+,\cdot)$ of $\mathsf{PA}$.

I'm not sure what your proposed definition of definability is getting at. One key issue with your proposed definition is that **definability only makes sense for subsets of (Cartesian powers of) the structure**; it doesn't make sense to ask whether $X$ is definable in $\mathfrak{A}$ if $X\not\subseteq\mathfrak{A}^n$ for some $n$. Note that this indicates an abuse of terminology in the present situation: when we say "$Th(\mathfrak{N})$ is undefinable in $\mathfrak{N}$" what we really mean is "$\{\#(\varphi): \varphi\in Th(\mathfrak{N})\}$ is undefinable in $\mathfrak{N}$."  To drive this point home, note that every countable set is in bijection with some definable subset of $\mathfrak{N}$, so that wouldn't give a useful notion.

---

OK, now let's turn to the **statement** of Tarski's undefinability theorem. The usual "concrete" version of Tarski is the following: "$\{\#(\varphi):\mathfrak{N}\models\varphi\}$ is undefinable in $\mathfrak{N}$," where $\mathfrak{N}$ is as mentioned above the standard model of arithmetic and "$\#$" is the usual Godel numbering map. Note that - as indicated earlier - **theories and provability are not mentioned here at all**.

The result above may feel a bit arbitrary; this is especially true since we often want to apply Tarski outside of the realm of $\mathfrak{N}$ specifically (e.g. to the whole set-theoretic universe). Rather than proving a new version of Tarski each time we need it, there is a more general form of the theorem which says roughly that if $\mathfrak{A}$ is a structure and $f$ is a map from the set of sentences in the language of $\mathfrak{A}$ to $\mathfrak{A}$ satisfying some basic properties, then $$\{f(\varphi):\mathfrak{A}\models\varphi\}$$ is not a definable subset of $\varphi$.

---

Now we're finally in a position to talk about how it's used. Often it appears not literally as a step in a proof, but rather as an indicator that a given proof attempt will not work (and indeed that the opposite result is likely true). For example, the natural way to attempt to show that the function $F$ sending $n$ to the least natural number not definable in $\mathfrak{N}$ by a first-order formula of length $<n$ is  definable in $\mathfrak{N}$ would be to try to directly express "the least natural number not definable in $\mathfrak{N}$ by a first-order formula of length $<n$" in the language of first-order arithmetic; but when unfolded, that relies on being able to talk about truth in a definable way, which Tarski says we can't do.

Note that this isn't yet a proof that $F$ isn't definable in $\mathfrak{N}$ - maybe there's some clever other way to define it - but it kills the obvious approach and strongly suggests that $F$ isn't definable. The actual proof that $F$ is undefinable however is strongly indicated by the proof of Tarski's theorem, so we generally get away with saying "By Tarski, $F$ isn't definable."

- That said, Tarski also gets used more "directly." For an example I personally find quite neat see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578756/where-did-the-language-in-this-proof-of-godels-incompleteness-appear), where a slight generalization of the usual "concrete" phrasing of the theorem can be used to prove the first incompleteness theorem.
- Also, note that the way you've stated $(1)$ is incorrect: the least natural number $k_{90}$ not definable in $\mathfrak{N}$ by a formula with $<90$ symbols is definable in $\mathfrak{N}$, since indeed *every* natural number is definable in $\mathfrak{N}$, but the *formula* "the least natural number not definable in $\mathfrak{N}$ by a formula with $<z$ symbols" is not definable in $\mathfrak{N}$.